# How to implement view pager in childview of expandable listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, expandablelistview

I have a requirement to implement expandable list view with view pager.I am successfully loading the expandable list view. when i click on expandable list view group item, child view is not loading the view pager and it's not giving any error.
How to implement view pager in child view of expandable list view?

Please help me...Thanks in advance...
below is the sample code....

```
@Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       object1 = list.get(groupPosition);
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = initFragmentUI(inflater, convertView, object1);
       return convertView;
   }

   public View initFragmentUI(LayoutInflater inflater, View listView, Object object1){
        ViewPager pager;
        FragementSliderPageAdapter sliderPageAdapter = null;
       listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, null);
       pager = (ViewPager) listView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
       List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
       // For all the different levels we are creating the Views for all the rounds.
       // So that user can see the previous rounds data also..
       //for (int i = object1.getRounds(); i >= 1; i--) {
       for (int i = 1; i <= object1.getRounds(); i++) {
           Fragment fragment = new FixtureSliderLayoutFragment();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putInt("index", i); // Our object is just an integer :stuck_out_tongue:
           args.putLong("_id", object1.getId());
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           fragments.add(fragment);
       }
       this.sliderPageAdapter = new FragementSliderPageAdapter(((Activity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
       this.pager.setAdapter(this.sliderPageAdapter);
       return listView;
   }
```

Comment: Where is code? Where is snapshot?

Comment: you should use Views instead of fragments in viewPager. use PagerAdapter and instantiateItem method to use view (instead of fragments list).

Comment: simply return the viewpager from onChildView of your adapter.

Comment: @Nepster, thank for reply inside the fragment i need list view.if views are using instead of fragments how to put listview?

Comment: create a seperate layout expandable_item and add a ListView their. And on instantiateItem read that Layout using View expandLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).(R.layout.expandable_item,null); and expandLayout .findViewByID(R.id.yourListView).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  collapsePager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                            parent.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                         ActivityExpeditionsExpandableView.expandableList.setScrollContainer(false);
                            break;

                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                         parent.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                         ActivityExpeditionsExpandableView.expandableList.setScrollContainer(true);
                            break;

                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                         parent.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                         ActivityExpeditionsExpandableView.expandableList.setScrollContainer(false);
                         break;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```